# How to perform Loop in SQL

Tags: sql, database

There are the 4 tables in the database.

- Movie (MovieID, MovieTitle, DirectorID)
- Director (DirectorID, DirectorName)
- Theatre (TheatreID, TheatreName)
- MovieinTheatre (MovieID, TheatreID)

Retrieve list of directors(names) who have all there movies in all the theatres.

I figured how to do it in python. But for this problem, I need the solution only in SQL.

The first step would be to find distinct director ids and the movie ids associated with each. Second would be to loop over MovieinTheatre table to find all the TheatreIDs. This is where I am stuck in SQL.

```
select distinct MovieID 
from Movie 
where DirectorID in { select dictinct DirectorID in Movie }
```

Comment: You actually basically have it in your example. Just change the {} to (). Read up on subqueries.

Comment: Without doing _all_ your homework: a solution would be to `SELECT COUNT(MovieID)` based on some criteria compared to `COUNT(MovieID)` based on some other criteria. I hope this hint is helpful.

Comment: The problem is in your question "How to do a loop". SQL is not a procedural language it is a set-based language. So think of how to find intersections in the data that answer your question. The answer below is on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Do a count of theaters:

  ```
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Theatre
  ```
- Read the `MovieinTheatre` table and find movies that are in all theaters:

  ```
  SELECT MovieID
    FROM MovieinTheatre
   GROUP BY MovieID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = ( subquery above goes here )
  ```
- Read the `Movie` table and find directors where all the movies are in all theaters:

  ```
  SELECT DirectorID
    FROM ( SELECT DirectorID
                , CASE WHEN MovieID NOT IN ( subquery above goes here )
                       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MissingCount
             FROM Movie
         ) x
   GROUP BY DirectorID
  HAVING SUM(MissingCount) = 0
  ```
- Read the `Director` to get the `DirectorName`:

  ```
  SELECT DirectorName
    FROM Director
   WHERE DirectorID IN ( subquery above goes here )
  ```

Now merge it all into a single query. For better performance and readability, you might want to use a `WITH` clause.

```
WITH MoviesInAllTheatres AS (
    SELECT MovieID
      FROM MovieinTheatre
     GROUP BY MovieID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Theatre )
), DirectorsInAllTheatres AS (
    SELECT DirectorID
      FROM ( SELECT DirectorID
                  , CASE WHEN MovieID NOT IN ( SELECT MovieID FROM MoviesInAllTheatres )
                         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MissingCount
               FROM Movie
           ) x
     GROUP BY DirectorID
    HAVING SUM(MissingCount) = 0
)
SELECT DirectorName
  FROM Director
 WHERE DirectorID IN ( SELECT DirectorID FROM DirectorsInAllTheatres )
```

Or, if you don't use `WITH` clause:

```
SELECT DirectorName
  FROM Director
 WHERE DirectorID IN (
          SELECT DirectorID
            FROM ( SELECT DirectorID
                        , CASE WHEN MovieID NOT IN (
                             SELECT MovieID
                               FROM MovieinTheatre
                              GROUP BY MovieID
                             HAVING COUNT(*) = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Theatre )
                          ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MissingCount
                     FROM Movie
                 ) x
           GROUP BY DirectorID
          HAVING SUM(MissingCount) = 0
       )
```